# What is best practice for allow unregistered/registered users to comment for a post?

Tags: database

I have a table which stores users, another table which stores post information and a third table which stores comments.

I want to allow unregistered *and* registered users to comment on posts.

What is the best practice database design for that? How should I store unregistered or registered commenter information in the database?

Comment: This is REALLY unspecific. Give us some context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dummy user record with the name, email, website of the guest user in your users table and link the comment to the dummy user's ID.

**Edit:** Given the additional information you've added in comments:

Create a basic `Users` table with

- ID
- Name
- Email
- Website

Create a second `RegisteredUsers` table with the additional fields you require for registered users and define the relationship between the two tables as Users.Id = RegisteredUsers.Id.

The `Comments` table would then have a `CreatedByUserId` field where `CreatedByUserId = Users.Id`.

Comment: but my registered users have very column in users table,In which case must set another column to null,which this is very bad idea!

Comment: It's hard for us to comment if you don't share your table schema. You may be best splitting your users table into two, one for the basic fields, and a second for the additional registered user fields.

Comment: this is good idea which i store unregistered info in a guest table,and add a IsGuest field to comment table with bit type and save in userid field of comment table userid from users table OR guest table?

Comment: I would store basic user data for *all* users in the basic User table, then the join for comment author would be much simpler.

Comment: then relation between basic info table and additional info table is required or optional?

Comment: It would be optional and via the ID in the BasicUser table.

Answer (score 1):

Put `null` in the `userID` field of the comment table for comments made by guests, or better yet, make a new user called "Guest" and assign the comment to them.

Alternatively, add a new column to the comments table called `guest` or something similar.  Make it a boolean value and turn it on for guest comments, and off for registered user comments.

There are loads of methods and no one of them is the "correct" way.  Use whichever one works best for your system.

Comment: very good,but i want store unregistered users information for comment(such as name,email,website),now what is your answer?

Comment: Sounds like that's all the info they need to sign up...

Comment: I'd vote for the "Guest" user, over the `null` value.

Comment: This is unspecific for me.give me some context.

Comment: @KiarashSZ: Don't criticise if you don't provide enough context in the first place. We're only trying to help you ;-)